# MS SQL function not returning value to C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, nullreferenceexception, executescalar

I've got the following MS SQL function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_NumApplications] ()
RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @numRecords int = 0
SELECT @numRecords = COUNT(A.id) FROM Applications A
RETURN @numRecords
END
```

and the following C# code to call the function:

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(mydbconnstring))
{
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.fn_numApplications", conn))
    {
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        //execute
        conn.Open();
        string retVal = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
        conn.Close();
    }
}
```

When the function gets to cmd.ExecuteScalar(), I am getting a NullReferenceException.

I have tried calling the function with, and without "dbo.".  I have also tried calling it using cmd.ExecuteReader() without success.

What's going wrong here?

Comment: Not only do you need the parenthesis and the SELECT keyword, but if you have a case sensitive collation this will throw an exception because the name of the function does not have a capital N in your c# code. Of course I would suggest making this into an inline table valued function instead.

Comment: You're missing the SELECT statement in front of the dbo.MyFunction.  You should run the code in SSMS first......to learn the syntax

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select dbo.fn_numApplications()", conn)`